# Forward email from a private network to a public email address under Linux (Debian)

Tags: email

We have a small private network and have added some devices that send notifications by email (not SMS). What I'd like to be able to do is have the emails sent by these devices to my public email address.

There is a server on the network that is connected to to both our private network and the internet that could do the deed